# Vb.net using mysql as back end

Tags: mysql

- I am doing project in vb.net 2010 as front end and mysql as back end.
- In mysql i have declared an attribute "contact no" as integer with size 11.
- During run time while entering contactno with 10 characters mysql shows an error that the value to the contact number is large.